# String parameter to lua function suddenly goes null

Tags: string, lua

My lua function looks like below. The parameter "scandate" is pased from c++ to the lua function. The printed output of the first line shows the date, and thereafter, any operation on the string indicates the string suddenly became null or empty.

```
function DoCustomLookup(wkItem,wkfId,wkevid,lookupTableID,scandate,lookuptext,lookupval,evtAlertText,newvalue,xtraFld1,xtraFld2,xtraFld3,xtraFld4,newStatus,newStatusDesc,errFlags) 
    local rslt = "Script error"  
    print (scandate)
    local scYY = scandate.sub(1,4)
    local scMM = scandate.sub(7,2)
    local scDD = scandate.sub(10,2)  
     print (scYY)
     print (scMM)
     print (scDD)
     local scandt = #scandate
     print (scandt)
    scYY,scMM, scDD = scandate.match("(%d+)%-(%d+)%-(%d+)%s.+")
...
end
```

Here is the console output:

```
2015-12-10 01:00:02


0
19
Workflow script error. Line :17: bad argument #2 to 'match' (string expected, got no value)
```

So it appears to me that the string simply vanishes in thin air. 
Can someone please explain what is going on and how I can keep the string? The strange thing is that substrings do not work, but the string length still prints 19. Then match also keeps failing (That is why I tried the substr as alternative)

Here is my code calling it from c++. You will notice I copy the date to a temporary buffer. I thought maybe the std::string.c_str() maybe got out of scope, but it did not change wheter I pass the date as std::string or from a c buffer.

```
bool LuaScript::DoCustomLookup(int wkItem, int wkfId, int wkevid, const int lookupTableID, const std::string scantime,
    const std::string& lookuptext, const std::string& lookupval, const std::string evtAlertText, 
    std::string& newvalue,
    const std::string xtraFld1, const std::string xtraFld2, const std::string xtraFld3, const std::string xtraFld4,
    int& newStatus, std::string& newStatusDesc, AlertFlags& errFlags, std::string& errMsg)
{     
    errMsg = "";
    char **date**[50];
    sprintf(date, "%s", scantime.c_str());
    lua_getglobal(L, "DoCustomLookup");     // get function
    lua_pushinteger(L, wkItem);     // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushinteger(L, wkfId);      // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushinteger(L, wkevid);     // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushinteger(L, lookupTableID);      // push parameter on call stack 
    lua_pushstring(L, **date**);    // push parameter on call stack 
    lua_pushstring(L, lookuptext.c_str());  // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushstring(L, lookupval.c_str());   // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushstring(L, evtAlertText.c_str());    // push parameter on call stack  
    lua_pushstring(L, newvalue.c_str());    // push parameter on call stack         
    lua_pushstring(L, xtraFld1.c_str());    // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushstring(L, xtraFld2.c_str());    // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushstring(L, xtraFld3.c_str());    // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushstring(L, xtraFld4.c_str());    // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushinteger(L, newStatus);      // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushstring(L, newStatusDesc.c_str());   // push parameter on call stack
    lua_pushinteger(L, errFlags);       // push parameter on call stack

    int rslt = lua_pcall(L, 16, 1, 0);
```

Thank you

Comment: You name your variable `scandate` but the error message says you are using the variable `scanDate`; Lua is case sensitive

Comment: Sorry, the stars around the parameter were intended to bold, now they appear like syntax errors. I do not see an option to edit and correct the display.

Comment: Yes, it is lowercase - I re-typed, tried to make bold for better reading and just messed it up. Please ignore the scanDate, it should be scandate, and the problem still remains.

Comment: Here is the actual code again:
 print (scandate)
 local scYY = scandate.sub(1,4)
 local scMM = scandate.sub(7,2)
 local scDD = scandate.sub(10,2)  
  print (scYY)
  print (scMM)
  print (scDD)
  local scandt = #scandate
  print (scandt)
 scYY,scMM, scDD = scandate.match("(%d+)%-(%d+)%-(%d+)%s.+")
And actual code.
2015-12-10 01:00:02


0
19
Workflow script error. Line :17: bad argument #2 to 'match' (string expected, got no value)

Comment: `scandate.sub(i,j)`? Should that be `scandate:sub(i,j)`? (`:` instead of `.`)

Comment: Thanks for the ':', I now get the substrings. I noticed my i,j indexes were wrong anyway, offset-offset, and not offset-length. The match is still not working, but I will manage with the substrings. Thanks !!

Comment: Same problem: use `scandate:match` instead of `scandate.match`.